# Disallow standard Users from generating Resultant Set of Policy data

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy, windows-server

how to restrict users to see Rsop data
such as

```
gpresult /r /x
```

and all data in group policy managements

i mean i want users can't see any Rsop data

i want if users opened group policy managements or type gpresult they get access denied or get nothing

we use windows server 2016 and all clients have windows 10

thank you for your attention

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell? This is neither a PowerShell code issue nor a PowerShell feature. ***gpresult*** is an executable. If you don't want people to use it, then delete it from their machines, or this is why Windows SRP/Applicker exists.  One can still get this detail in other ways as it's just registry settings. For ```rsop.mmc```, I am not aware of a way to permanently remove that addon from MMC.exe. Why are you trying to do this? Admins need this tool on workstations for troubleshooting? Why would you not want users to know this?

Comment: @postanote Because in our organization, some access is closed for some people and it is open for some, and users should not know the differences because this is the request of our company's management.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style why you deleted the answer ?